# AWS SSO provision permission set automatically through cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-sso

I have created `AWS SSO permission sets` through `CloudFormation` and users are successfully assuming roles in downstream accounts. The issue I am seeing here is when a new change gets added to the code, let's say IAM inline policy gets edited with some extra permissions, I need to login into the account and manually provision the changes from main account to the downstream accounts.

I found `provision-permission-set` AWS CLI call but it doesn't look like there is a `CloudFormation` option.

I am considering having this step as a part of my deployment pipeline and if I don't have to create a custom script that is going to use AWS CLI to do that job that would be awesome.

Thanks y'all

Comment: Unfortunately AWS SSO doesn't have full API coverage as of today, so a fully-automated SSO setup isn't possible. They released some improved coverage late last year, but still waiting for the fully API. I'm guessing that's a precursor to CloudFormation support. If you've got a TAM then +1 it on the team's roadmap to hopefully speed it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AWS::SSO::Assignment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sso-assignment.html) to join the permission set, principal and account.